# Prevent Pytest from reusing app object between different test files

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

I have a project with multiple route files, each of which has an `APIRouter`. I include all routers in my `main.py` as follows:

```py
from init import app
import customer
import receipt

app.include_router(customer.router, prefix='/api/customer', tags=["Customer"])
app.include_router(receipt.router, prefix='/api/receipt', tags=["Receipt"])
```

`init.py`:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
```

In `customer.py` I have this (simplified) code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel

router = APIRouter()

class CustomerModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

@router.post('/')
def register_new_customer(data: CustomerModel):
    pass
```

in my `receipt.py` I have similar code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel

router = APIRouter()

class ReceiptModel(BaseModel):
    price: float

@router.post('/')
def add_new_receipt(data: ReceiptModel):
    pass
```

I also have unit tests for both files. `test_receipt.py`:

```py
from receipt import router
from init import app

app.include_router(router)
client = TestClient(app)

class TestReceiptsRoutes:
    def test_can_create_new_receipt(self):
        response = client.post('/', json={'price': 10.0})
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

and similar for `test_customer.py`

If i run each file individually, e.g. `pytest test_receipt.py` or `pytest test_customer.py` it works fine, but when i run them together, my `test_receipt.py` fails, saying `response.status_code` is `422`. What happens is that my `app` adds both POST routes on `/` path, so when receipt runs the test, it's actually making a call to the customer route and fails validation.

Question: how can I ensure that `app` is not reused between test files?

I know I can just copy/paste the `app.include_router` lines from main into the tests (with full paths), and that's what I'm currently doing as a workaround, I was just wondering if there's a way to ensure that app is isolated b/w each test suite.

Comment: Perhaps you could reload the `init` module, e.g. `from importlib import reload` and then `reload(init)` and then re-import `from init import app`. You could add that to your `setUp` method if you're using `unittest.TestCase` or to your fixture if you're using modern `pytest`, see e.g. https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `app` object is stateful, it might help to reload the `init` module and then re-import `app`.

Here's how you might do it using a fixture:

```py
import pytest
from importlib import reload

import init


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = reload(init).app
    app.include_router(foo.router, ...)
    return app


def test_foo(app):
    client = TestClient(app)
    ...
```